# QObject::findChild() returns None without obvious reason

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, qt5, pyqt5

I'm new to Qt Quck and Qt5/PyQt, and now I've faced a strange problem. I'm trying to find an object with objectName "test" in the below QML definition like this:

```
self.rootObject().findChild(QObject, "test")
```

But the call returns None. However, if I move the `objectName: "test"` property to the parent Tab element, then it's found successfully. It's only not found whem inside the child `Item`. Similarly, `addChannel`, `modifyChannel` and `removeChannel` objects are also not found by `findChild()`.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import "TouchStyles"

Item {
    ListModel { }

    TouchButtonFlatStyle { id: touchButtonFlat }
    TouchTabViewStyle { id: touchTabView }

    Rectangle {
        width: 480
        height: 230

        TabView {
            currentIndex: 0
            tabPosition: 1
            anchors.fill: parent
            style: touchTabView

            Tab {
                title: "Play"

                Item {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    PianoKeyboard { anchors.centerIn: parent }
                }
            }
            Tab {
                title: "Channels"
                Item {
                    objectName: "test"
                    ListView {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        model: listModel
                        delegate: Channel {}
                    }
                    BorderImage {
                        border.bottom: 8
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        source: "images/toolbar.png"
                        width: parent.width
                        height: 50

                        RowLayout {
                            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

                            Button { text: "Add"; objectName: "addChannel" }
                            Button { text: "Modify"; objectName: "modifyChannel" }
                            Button { text: "Remove"; objectName: "removeChannel" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The Qt documentation says that the search is performed recursively. Why doesn't it traverse the entire object tree?

Comment: Your best bet would be to first check if the search succeeds from C++. If it doesn't, report it as a Qt bug. Otherwise, it'd be a PyQt bug.

Comment: What is the result of `self.rootObject().findChildren(QObject)` (i.e. all children)?

Comment: Does the same thing happen with the first tab (so if you copy second tab's Item to first tab)? Alternately, if you select the 2nd tab before doing the findChild, same problem?

Comment: @Schollii, I moved the contents of the 2nd tab to the first one, and then the item is found (and addChannel item is also found). When it's in the 2nd tab, it's not found o_O

Comment: Now it's even more strange: I've given each Tab an unique `objectName`, and I first do findChild() for the Tab, and then using the found Tab, call its findChild() to get the child element of the Tab. And guess what? The child Tab is found always (no matter if it's the first Tab or not), but the child element inside the Tab is found only if the Tab is first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that tabs are "instantiated" only on demand. The first tab is always instantiated, so if you put the `objectName` there it will be found.

It will be found in the second tab only if you instantiate the second tab (select it). Similarly, using `findChild` on the `TabView` probably instantiates each tab (since it looking for them), so after that a `findChild` works even if second tab was not selected.

Conclusion: instantiate all tabs first (doing a `findChild` on the `TabView` is one way but may be a hack), then do the `findChild` for the item.

Comment: I executing `findChild` on the root element to find the TabView (found), then execute `findChild` on the TabView to find the Tab (found), then execute `findChild` on the Tab to find the Button (not found). The problem is reproduced if I run it on my desktop PC (previously I tested it on embedded ARM board). So, the Tab isn't instantiated by `findChild`. Also, I looked at the source code for TabView, and I didn't find any lazy loading logic there, except for the style of the TabView. Running `findChildren(QObject)` on the found Tab returns two children: a QObject and a QQmllComponent.

Comment: Solved by connecting to `onCurrentIndexChanged` event of `TabView`. Once the event gets fired, getting `currentIndex` of the active `Tab`, and then, based on the index calling a function to connect to signals of the (now instantiated) `Tab` children.